# Real roots of Irrational equation

Tags: calculus, polynomials, radicals, substitution

> Find he number of real roots of the following equation.
>    $$x^{\frac{1}{7}}-x^{\frac{1}{5}} = x^{\frac{1}{3}}-x^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$

$\bf{Attempt:}$ with Hit and Trial, Clearly $x=0,x=1$ are the roots of above equation.

Assuming $$f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{7}}-x^{\frac{1}{5}}-x^{\frac{1}{3}}+x^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Then $$f'(x) = \frac{1}{7}x^{-\frac{6}{7}}-\frac{1}{5}x^{-\frac{4}{5}}-\frac{1}{3}x^{-\frac{2}{3}}+\frac{1}{2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}}.$$

Could some help me how to solve it, Thanks

Comment: Three roots  $x=0,0.011 ,x=1$

Answer (score 2):

There is another root.

Let $x=a^{210}$, where $a\geq0$.

Thus, we need to solve
$$a^{30}-a^{42}=a^{70}-a^{105}$$ or
$$a^{30}(a^{75}-a^{40}-a^{12}+1)=0$$ or
$$a^{30}(a^{40}(a^{35}-1)-(a^{12}-1))=0$$ or
$$a^{30}(a-1)(a^{40}(a^{34}+a^{33}+...+a+1)-(a^{11}+a^{10}+...+a+1))=0$$
and since $35\ne12$,  by the Descartes's rule we see that there is another unique root on $(0,1)$.

About the Descartes's rule see here:
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs

Comment: There's quite a bit more to it than $35 \ne 12$.

Comment: @Robert Israel  No! Use the Descartes's   rule.

Comment: Could you please add that part in your solution?

Comment: I meant step by step.

Comment: @john nobody I added something. See now please.